# Should meta.stackexchange.com redirect to meta.stackoverflow.com?

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, 500-server-error

Going to [meta.stackexchange.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com) will give you a **503 Service Unavailable** error. Since this meta is the de facto meta for the entire network, wouldn't it make since to redirect it here?

If not, I'm curious about the reasons for not doing so.

Comment: I tried and [meta.stackexchange.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com) redirects to MSO. [meta.stackexhange.com](http://meta.stackexhange.com), however, leads to some uninteresting list of spam links. Not sure if it got fixed in the process or it was a typo from the beginning.

Comment: @Dennis Interesting. The "[meta.stackexchange.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com/)" link *in your comment* shows me a "503 Service Unavailable" error, like RLH reported.

Comment: @JeremyBanks: Nevermind. Chrome had already cached the 301. I tried in IE and got the error.

Comment: Aaaand it's fixed!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it shouldn't. The problem was that there was two definitions in the zone file - i've fixed it so that meta.stackexchange.com now only has one DNS entry.

So this won't affect everyone equally - depends on which response you get back first. This should clear up in about half an hour (unless you have a crappy DNS provider who ignores our TTLs)

```
C:\Users\gbeech>nslookup meta.stackexchange.com
Server:  ny-dc01.ds.stackexchange.com
Address:  10.7.0.60

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    meta.stackexchange.com
Addresses:  64.34.119.12
          64.34.80.165
```

This just cropped up because Fog Creek finally shut down those load balancers that were forwarding the traffic to us.

Comment: Rebecca is involved? It's a conspiracy!!!

Comment: @animuson nah she just didn't like my bad spelling

Comment: If that were true, she would have fixed the word "do" in the last sentence there. :o

Comment: @animuson what word do?

Comment: @animuson gotta keep you guessing.